# How to create a numpy array from 2 lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a count of integer frequencies that I am trying to get into an array. L1 are the integers from 1 to 9, but only if they occur, I want to use this as the array index. L2 is the frequency of the integer and I want that to be entered in the array.

`L1 = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`  #no twos occurred in the data so 2 is not in L1

`L2 = [6,7,1,2,8,4,2,1]`

The out put I want to get is: `A1 = [[6,0,7],[1,2,8],[4,2,1]]`
I feel like I'm missing something but this is my last attempt:

```
for num in L1 and count in L2:
    a1[:num] = L2[:count]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the list arrays for ease of use:

```
In [286]: L1 = np.array([1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
     ...: L2 = np.array([6,7,1,2,8,4,2,1])
```

Make a place to put values:

```
In [287]: res = np.zeros(10,int)
In [288]: res[L1]
Out[288]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [289]: res[L1]=L2
In [290]: res
Out[290]: array([0, 6, 0, 7, 1, 2, 8, 4, 2, 1])
```

oops, offset a bit.

```
In [291]: res = np.zeros(10,int)
In [292]: res[L1-1]=L2
In [293]: res
Out[293]: array([6, 0, 7, 1, 2, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0])
```

correct the initial size, and reshape:

```
In [294]: res = np.zeros(9,int)
In [295]: res[L1-1]=L2
In [296]: res.reshape(3,3)
Out[296]: 
array([[6, 0, 7],
       [1, 2, 8],
       [4, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you!